# Check if string contains any list element

Tags: python, list

So I am doing a for loop of a list. Every single string, I want to .find, but instead of .find one item for a string, I want to check that string for anything in my list.

For example.

```
checkfor = ['this','that','or the other']
```

then do

string.find(checkfor) or something, so I'd like to do this:

```
if email.find(anything in my checkforlist) == -1:
    do action
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the positions of everything in that list, or are you trying to check if anything in that list is contained in your string?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to know if at least one value in the list exists in the string then a simple way to do that would be:

```
any(email.find(check) > -1 for check in checkfor)
```

If you want to check that all of them exist in the string then do

```
all(email.find(check) > -1 for check in checkfor)
```

Or if you want the exact values that did have a match in the string you can do:

```
matches = [match for match in checkfor if email.find(match) > -1]
```

I would prefer to use:

```
check in email
```

over

```
email.find(check) > -1
```

but I guess it can depend on your use case (the above examples would probably look better with the `in` operator).

Depending on your case, you may prefer to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), but I won't get into that here.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check that string for anything in my list

Python has `in` for that.

```
for s in checkfor:
    if s in email:
        # do action
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using list comprehension to accomplish this.

```
occurrences = [i for i, x in enumerate(email) if x =='this']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `in` clause:

```
If checkfor not in email:
    do_some_thing()
```